# Multiple Output with OutputResponse in Mathematica

Tags: control-systems

I have a question here regarding how to derive multiple output from OutputResponse or in general. Here is a screenshot of the codes[image]

As seen, I have only one quantity plotted. Tried google but didn't manage to find a solution.

Thanks in advance!

The codes are here:

```
ω = 2. Pi*50; Mag = 1; θ = 0.;

Tαβ2dqInv22 = {{Cos[ω t], -Sin[ω t]}, 
{Sin[ω t], Cos[ω t]}};
Tαβ2dq22 = {{Cos[ω t], 
    Sin[ω t]}, {-Sin[ω t], Cos[ω t]}};

Inputαβ22 = {Mag Cos[ω t + θ], 
   Mag Cos[ω t + θ]};
(*Inputαβ22={Mag ,Mag};*)

Outαβ2dq22 = 
  FullSimplify[Tαβ2dq22.Inputαβ22] // 
   TrigReduce;

g[t_] = OutputResponse[
   TransferFunctionModel[(0.67/(0.0025 s + 1) + 1)/(0.0025 s), s], 
   Outαβ2dq22[[1]], t];
f[t_] = OutputResponse[
   TransferFunctionModel[(0.67/(0.0025 s + 1) + 1)/(0.0025 s), s], 
   Outαβ2dq22[[2]], t];

Plot[{g[t], f[t]}, {t, 0, 0.2}, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? The response to the two inputs:

```
res = Chop@Expand@
OutputResponse[
 TransferFunctionModel[(0.67/(0.0025*s + 1) + 1)/(0.0025*s), 
  s], #1, t] & /@ Outαβ2dq22;
Plot[res, {t, 0, 0.05}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is what I want! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Suba has already done it.

```
tf = TransferFunctionModel[(0.67/(0.0025 s + 1) + 1)/(0.0025 s), s];
Outαβ2dq22 = FullSimplify[Tαβ2dq22.Inputαβ22] // TrigReduce // Chop;
Plot[Outαβ2dq22, {t, 0, 0.1}]
```

This is your input:

[image]

```
out1 = OutputResponse[tf, Outαβ2dq22[[1]], {t, 0, 0.2}];
out2 = OutputResponse[tf, Outαβ2dq22[[2]], {t, 0, 0.2}];

out3 = OutputResponse[tf, #, {t, 0, 0.2}] & /@ Outαβ2dq22;
```

You get the same output with out1 + out2 or out3:

```
Plot[{out1, out2}, {t, 0, 0.2}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[out3, {t, 0, 0.2}]
```

[image]

You have a network that only one source works. If both sources act, they must be linked to each other. Now a network on which two sources work and thus the answer to your question at the beginning " I have a question here regarding how to derive multiple output from OutputResponse or in general."

[image]

```
g1 = (uR - u1) s C1 + uR/R + (uR - u2)/(s L1);
sol = Solve[g1 == 0, uR];
iR = uR/R /. sol;
h1 = iR/u1 /. u2 -> 0; 
h2 = iR/u2 /. u1 -> 0;
tf = TransferFunctionModel[{Join[h1, h2]}, s]
```

[image]

```
T = 10^-3;
params= {L1 -> 1, C1 -> 0.1*10^-6, R -> 1000};
q1 = SquareWave[{0, 1}, (t + T/4)/T]; 
q2 = SawtoothWave[{0, 1}, t/T];
out = OutputResponse[tf /. params, {q1, q2}, {t, 0, 5 T}];

Show[
 Plot[{q1, 1000 out}, {t, 0, 5 T}, ExclusionsStyle -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}],
 Plot[q2, {t, 0, 5 T}, ExclusionsStyle -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Darker[Red]]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for another solution to the problem! Strangely, when I use function without defining time range in OutputResponse, the plot seems wrong. Why is that?
`g[t_] = OutputResponse[tf, Out\[Alpha]\[Beta]2dq22[[1]], t];'
f[t_] = OutputResponse[ResoantFilter, Out\[Alpha]\[Beta]2dq22[[2]], t];
Plot[{g[t], f[t]}, {t, 0, 0.2}]`

Comment: Peng, look at the output of $f[t]$ or $g[t]$. Then you will see why I used `Chop` and `Expand`. If you add that, I think the problems you are seeing will go away.

Comment: @rewi a lot for me to learn from your latter part. Thanks!

Comment: @Suba Thomas you were right. I can see what Chop is doing but for expand, I am not sure how it helps...

Comment: Peng, I used `Expand` to get a cleaner picture of what was getting chopped.

Comment: Peng, see my comment under http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134138/5998, where not using `Expand` can cause issues.