# Limiting transfer function of PID to upper and lower bounds

Tags: control-systems

I have a question about Limiting the output of a transfer function in my system model.
(Im fairly new to control theory and control systems)

I have a model where a PID controller is directly controlling the acceleration of a quadcopter. The quadcopter is "trying" to fly at a set hight.

Currently, I have the following:
[image: Copter PID]

My question is: how can I limit the acceleration (the PID output) in the system?

I've tried the solution from question [133541](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133541/how-to-set-a-limit-and-initial-value-for-transfer-function-in-mathematica). But that didn't work out for me. Mathematica tells me the transfer function of the PID controller cant be converted into a nonlinearStateSpaceModel? I don't really know why or how as I'm new to the field.

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core problem is that [`NonlinearStateSpaceModel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearStateSpaceModel.html) does not support descriptor systems.

When there are pure derivative terms, the state-space representation will need a singular descriptor matrix. This is supported by [`StateSpaceModel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StateSpaceModel.html) but not by [`NonlinearStateSpaceModel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearStateSpaceModel.html).

```
Through@{StateSpaceModel, NonlinearStateSpaceModel}@TransferFunctionModel[s, s]
```

> [image]

A workaround is to do away with the derivative term or use a filter on the derivative terms. (These are done in applications where there is large sensor noise or abrupt reference changes.)

```
SystemsModelSeriesConnect[TransferFunctionModel[kp + ki/s + kd s/(s + α), s], 
 NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{{}, Clip[u]}, {}, u]]
```

> [image]

Comment: Is there a mathematical reason NonlinearStateSpaceModels don't support pure derivative terms? Or is that just a Mathematica thing? Anyways the filter is working like a charm so thanks! :D

Comment: It's not a mathematical reason. We did not get to it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the double pole representing the copter, a simple PD will suffice. Follows a layman procedure to find an acceptable solution. The procedure consists in searching through a minimization procedure, the nearest response regarding a reference response to a step. Here the reference response is given by

```
stepref = InverseLaplaceTransform[(a^2 + b^2)/((s + a)^2 + b^2)/s, s, t]
```

the actual step response is obtained as follows:

```
PID = kp + ki/s + s kd;
COPTER = 1/s^2;
model = COPTER PID/(1 + COPTER PID)
stepresponse = InverseLaplaceTransform[model/s, s, t];
```

then follows the minimization procedure

```
parms = {a -> 2, b -> 2};
tmax = 4;
n = 20;
stepref0 = stepref /. parms;
tab = Sum[Abs[stepresponse - stepref0], {t, 0, tmax, tmax/n}];
sol = NMinimize[{tab, kp > 0, ki > 0, kd > 0}, {kp, ki, kd}]
stepresponse0 = stepresponse /. sol[[2]]
```

Follows a plot showing in blue the reference response and in red the response found.

[image]

Comment: Is there some place where you are clipping the signal between `PID` and `COPTER` to be within 2 units?

Comment: The acceleration limit at the PID can be obtained by conveniently choosing it's parameters. No need for Clip[]

Comment: were a, b -> 2 arbitrarily choosen? Or where did that come from...being matching a $e^{-a*t}$ sin($\omega$ t) for the system

Comment: Choosing $a, b$ we are choosing the needed unit step response for our COPTER + PID.